# SQL Server converting Varchar to date

Tags: sql-server, implicit-conversion

While insertion into a **varchar** field(on MS SQL Server) a text similar to "Jan 15, 2015", it is being stored as "15/01/2015". I am not sure what is happening here.  Why is this implicit casting being done and how can I prevent it?

Comment: What is the actual `insert` statement being executed? If this is coming from another program (not a query you're writing yourself in SSMS), have you verified that the program isn't changing the format of the date? Why are you storing a date as a `varchar` in the first place, instead of storing it as a date and then formatting for the user in the presentation layer?

Comment: Have to pile on here **don't** store dates as a `varchar`, store them as a `date`; it is awful practice storing dates as a `varchar` for so many reasons. It means, for example, doing a query like `WHERE CONVERT(Date,DateColumn) = '20180313'` isn't SARGable (meaning you can't use indexes, resulting in poor performance). It also means that a query like `WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN 'Apr 01, 2017' AND 'Jun 30, 2017'` *would* return values for April and June, but probably also values for July, January, February, August and December! Because `Jul, Jan, Feb, Aug, Dec` are `BETWEEN 'Apr' AND 'Jun'`.

Comment: @alroc: Since its the statement is a preparedStatement, I cannot access the query, but when I log the string right before adding it to the statement I get the normal exprected string, so no conversion till this point.

Comment: @Larnu: This is just a temporary dump DB and I have no plans to make any queries on these date fields.

Comment: @me_digvijay then you're getting an implicit conversion somewhere based on regional settings, perhaps your `PreparedStatement` has defined this field as a `date`? Either way, even if this is a "temporary dump database", just use the correct data types. Calling something "temporary" isn't a valid reason for using the wrong data types. You're just going to cause difficulty later.